# How to use a WHERE clause with Oracle JSON_OBJECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I am trying to produce some oracle records snapshots using JSON_OBJECT but, surprisingly it seems that I cannot use a variable in the clause statement?

```sql
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(
  person_id NUMBER,
  first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(person_id)
);

INSERT INTO SAMPLE (person_id, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (person_id, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES (2, 'Mary', 'Doe');

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  name VARCHAR2(50) := 'John';   
  jsonResult CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(*)
  INTO jsonResult
  FROM SAMPLE
  WHERE first_name = name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( jsonResult );
END;
```

> Error report:
> ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
> ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: hope the new example is of your liking

Comment: What database version are you using? It appears that `JSON_OBJECT(*)` was introduced in [Oracle 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370) so if you are using a [version prior to that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370) then you will have to list every key.

Comment: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: This looks to be a bug. The query works if you use a text literal but not with a PL/SQL variable. Trying `WHERE first_name = (SELECT name FROM DUAL);` gives an internal error.

Answer (score 1):

For now I found one, sad, workaround...
replacing the wildcard "*" for the list of columns.

This works:

```
-- WORKs!
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
   name VARCHAR2(50) := 'John';
   jsonResult CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(person_id, first_name, last_name ) INTO jsonResult FROM SAMPLE WHERE first_name = name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( jsonResult );
END;
```